# bug when i input value "45" i get "0.45e2" ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

i cant understand why when i input 45 i get 0.45e2 while any sting like pants work fine
i have the following html

```
<%= form_with(model: invoice, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if invoice.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(invoice.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this invoice from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
        <% invoice.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<center><h1>ΤΔΑ-ΤΙΜΟΛΟΓΙΟ-ΔΕΛΤΙΟΥ ΑΠΟΣΤΟΛΗΣ</h1></center>
<div align="right">

</div>

<pre>ID           CODE         DESCRIPTION  BASE CODE    QUANTITY     </pre>
<table style="border:2px solid black;"id="tableid">
<td><input  type="text" name="invoice[items][]" /></td>
<td><input  type="number" name="invoice[tax][]" /></td>
<td><input  type="number" name="invoice[discount][]" /></td>
<td><input  type="number" name="invoice[sum][]" /></td>
<td><input  type="number" name="invoice[price][]" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var table = document.getElementById("tableid");
    table.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) 
    {
    if (event.keyCode === 18)
     {
            event.preventDefault();
            var rowid=table.rows.length-1;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowid+1);
            row.id = (rowid+1).toString();
            var cell0 = row.insertCell(0);
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(2);
            var cell3 = row.insertCell(3);
            var cell4 = row.insertCell(4);
            cell0.innerHTML = "<input type='text'  size='8' name='invoice[items][]'></input>";
        cell1.innerHTML = "<input type='text'  size='8' name='invoice[tax][]'></input>";
        cell2.innerHTML = "<input type='text'  size='8' name='invoice[discount][]'></input>";
        cell3.innerHTML = "<input type='text'  size='8' name='invoice[sum][]'></input>";
        cell4.innerHTML = "<input type='text'  size='8' name='invoice[price][]'></input>";

      }
    });
</script>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and my controller

```
    def invoice_params
      params.require(:invoice).permit({:items => []}, {:price => []}, {:tax => []}, {:discount => []}, {:sum => []})
    end
```

so  this is happening when i create new items

```
Invoice was successfully created.

Items: ["pants", "spoon"]

Price: [0.45e2, 0.2e1]

Tax: [0.45e2, 0.25e2]

Discount: [0.45e2, 0.2e2]

Sum: [0.45e2, 0.22e2]

Edit | Back
```

should i  tell ruby on rails tat the params sum,tax,discoun is numeric or something like that?
or must be a better way to save the params ? as the string work fine

***UPDATE***
also if you change t.numeric to t.float solve the problem

Comment: because you have set decimal type of column in migration. It is not a bug at all

Comment: so what is the best type to save like 0.48 value ?

Comment: I guess you are doing fine with this already. Decimal is perfect type for storing float numbers

Comment: yea and i'm looking how to get the 0.45 without the e2 as in my database its saved as 0.45

Comment: `0.45e2 == 45 #⇒ true`. This is scientfic notation.

Comment: Yeah but i want to display 45 at users not 0.45e2, i found it

Comment: You can add `.to_i` or `.to_f` methods in your views if to make them more readable to humans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to avoid floating point numbers completely when dealing with money and convert to e.g. cents (or whatever your currency's smallest denomination is called) for storage. *If you know you'll only ever need to support one currency this will be simple.* Of course, you still want to allow for entering and displaying prices via decimal notation. Here's how I would approach that in your `Invoice` model, after creating new `price_cents` etc. columns and migrating the existing data:

```
  def price=(value)
    value = value.to_f if value.is_a? String
    self.price_cents = (value * 100).round
  end

  def price
    price_cents&.positive? ? price_cents / 100.0 : 0
  end
```

Comment: The proper way to deal with money is to use [`money`](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money) gem. Otherwise sooner or later one would find themselves in a position when they need to share €1 between three holders and _all_ the arithmetic would suddenly blow up. I am not saying that ¥ has no coins, OMR has 3 decimal points, and one still needs to be able to sum `¢0.1` and `¢0.2` which are perfectly valid values in the financial world and still get back `¢0.3`.